# How to send message to my customers (users) using Facebook

Tags: facebook

I have a list of facebook accounts of my customer. Is it possible to send notifications (messages) to them via facebook messenger? Any reference on code example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Messenger API can only be used to message users, that initiated concat with your page from their end. You can not use it to just arbitrarily contact users out of the blue.

What types of messages can be send and under what concitions, is listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages

I would suggest you go check that first of all, for whether any of the uses cases is applicable for what you want to do here.

Comment: Thanks. That was my understanding after reading FB API docs, but because I'm totally  new with FB  I decided to ask.